# LinearLayout is hidden behind the first LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

My first LinearLayout is being displayed correctly but the second LinearLayout gets hidden behind the first one. Here is the sample code that I use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout11" android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="70px" android:paddingTop="40px" android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingLeft="10px" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView111" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/home" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout12" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="70px" android:paddingTop="40px" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="70px" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView121" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/email" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout13" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="70px" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="70px" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView131" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/baby" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout14" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="70px" android:paddingTop="40px" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="60px" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView141" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/camera" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout15" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="10px" android:paddingTop="40px" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="10px" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView151" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/settings" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="500px" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout21" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="70px" android:paddingLeft="10px" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView211" android:textSize="20px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="In-Hospital" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout22" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="70px" android:paddingLeft="10px" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView221" android:textSize="20px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Home" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout23" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="70px" android:paddingLeft="10px" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView231" android:textSize="20px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Nursing" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone please tell me where I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It might help if you showed a mockup of what you'd expect to see, and then a screenshot of what you actually see. We don't know what your expectation is, and "correctly" doesn't really help.

Comment: oh my goodness, you shouldn't have this many declarations of LinearLayout. What are you trying to actually do?

Comment: Also, use dip instead of pixels!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outer LinearLayout has an orientation of horizontal, this means that the second LinearLayout should be being displayed to the right of the other one, not below it.  Try changing the orientation to vertical.

All of your pixel specific sizes are probably screwing things up as well.  You should never use pixels to layout your file.  If you really need to specify sizes, use dp.  However, I really doubt that you need to be setting most any of those sizes explicitly.

If you explain what you are actually trying to do, we can help you further.  Meanwhile, read through the docs on layouts.  There is a lot of good info there, especially [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Thanks, I changed the android:orientation="horizontal" of the first LinearLayout to vertical and it worked! :-).